# I am getting error in controller of textfield,I am new to flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

TextEditingController? name = TextEditingController();
TextField(
controller: name,
decoration:InputDecoration(
labelText: "name",
hintText: "name",
enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
borderSide: BorderSide(
color: Colors.red),[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Pox.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are trying to reassign a final variable in your initState(). Change your code to

```
late TextEditingController nameix;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    nameix = TextEditingController();
}

...
```

Everything else should be okay after the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the initialisation in `initState` and just keep the `final TextEditingController nameix = TextEditingController();` or directly say:

```
TextField(
    controller: TextEditingController(),
    ... ),
```